# How to get values from associative array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have a PHP script that outputs a JSON associative array when an ajax call is made to it. 
The first key and value in the array (["status" : "failed"]) shows the status. 
The second key and value (["message" : "Invalid Input"]) shows the message. 
So i need to first run a check whether the status is "failed", if it is, get the corresponding error message and vice versa.

The problem is how do I get the second key and value pair to get the message.

Here's the JavaScript I'm utilizing:

```
            var frmdata = new FormData($('#order-form')[0]);        
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'classes/validate.php',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,   
                data: frmdata,
                success: function(data) {
                    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                        if (key == "status") {
                            if (value == "failed") {

                            } else if (value == "success") {

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Here's the PHP script;

```
    public function outputJSON($status, $message)
    {
        $this->json_output["status"] = $status;
        $this->json_output["message"] = $message;
        $json = json_encode($this->json_output, true);
        return $json;
    }
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: How about having response `object` as `{status:'failed',message:'Invlaid Input'}`. You can read it like `data.status`

Comment: @aldrin27 Object {status: "failed", message: "Invalid service selected"}

Comment: @RayonDabre Can you give me an example?

Comment: Try: `if(data.status == 'failed') { alert(data.message); }else { data.message}`

Comment: See [what is JSON](http://json.org/), [how to use the JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), and [how it differs from the JavaScript objects](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset).

Comment: But I can make this my answer. :D

Comment: @aldrin27 Thanks, but i prefer Rayon's answer. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function outputJSON($status, $message) {
  $json = json_encode(array('status'=>$status,'message'=>$message));
  return $json;
}
```

```js
var frmdata = new FormData($('#order-form')[0]);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'classes/validate.php',
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  data: frmdata,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.status === 'failed') {
      alert(data.message);
    } else {
      //data.status is success
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.